# Custom image gallery on Android

Tags: android, mysql, image

I'm developing one Android application, now i need to implement a simple image gallery.

But the image are not saved in the device, the image must be loaded from a database.

In a database i have a direct link of image, when i open the gallery the images are loaded in real time, initially a thumbnail after the "tap" on the image the image is opened in fullscreen.

I have some images that i must show, then :

the first time i want show the images in a grid view (thumbnail), when i press on a single image, this image is opened in fullscreen mode.

How i can do this ?

Comment: With some kind of light box utility

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridView` to show thumbnail and for the full screen image launch new activity or custom dialog